# iPhone 6 stolen. Did I accidentally cancel my pending data erase by removing account from iCloud too soon?

Tags: icloud, security, iphone

I lost my iphone 6 maybe 2 hours ago and proceeded to do some damage control by accessing the Find My iPhone feature on iCloud. In the following order in the span of maybe 10 minutes, I turned the iPhone on Lost Mode, selected the  remote wipe, and selected "remove device from account." I also called my carrier to make sure the account with that phone is cancelled.

However...my iphone has been OFFLINE the whole time, including the time it was stolen. Since I selected the "erase data" and "remove device from account" fuctions while it was offline, will the data still be removed? I read somewhere that removing the device from the iCloud account might cancel the pending iphone data wipe. Does that mean the thief will have access to my phone and all its files? Or will my phone wipe automatically since I selected the "erase data" function? I just want to make sure the thief won't be able to access any of the data on that phone.

I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: How did you go about deleting the device from your iCloud account?

Comment: Apple really does need to add some do's and don'ts to the Find My iPhone page on iCloud.com  Everyone wants to remote wipe, and they should just stop at LOST MODE nowadays.

Comment: Remote Wipe is really only for business phones with sensitive data on, where the loss of the data is more important than the recovery of the phone. Once it's wiped & removed from iCloud, you just gave the thief the phone for free.

Comment: @bassplayer7 I was signed into iCloud on the browser, in the Find My iPhone page. I went to the drop-down menu to view all my devices. The only option left to select for the iphone was to remove it from the account, since I had already put it into Lost Mode and wiped the data. However...I am looking at my remaining devices and it looks like an iPhone 6 is still listed. I may have removed my old iPhone 4s account instead (I'm hoping!). But it looks like the phone 6 hasn't been connected to a network since it has been stolen.

Comment: If your iPhone 6 is still listed then you should be OK, unless you have it linked to a friends phone or something.

Comment: Why were you so quick to wipe the phone? That's disowning it. Thereon you've no hope of recovering it. An honest person can't call you with it to give it back, and you can't track it anymore. Assuming you had a passcode set, the phone is encrypted. You should only wipe it when all recovery options are exhausted. EDIT: You wouldn't have cancelled the erase, as the commands issued to the phone are queued in order. When the phone was next switched on, it'll carry out the commands in order, whether it was to display a message, make a noise, engage lost mode, then erase.

Answer (score 4):

It was really wrong that you have choosen to remove device from account. If you have passcode on it your data is probably safe but since you have removed it from your account it can now be restored as new without any iCloud lock whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

When it reconnects to a network it will go in lost mode and start deleting the files, but if the thief doesn't connect to one then all of your data will still be on the device. You shouldn't have removed it from your iCloud account because now if the person restores the device before connecting it to a network because now the phone can be restored and iCloud lock won't stop it. Its most likely that the thief will wipe it and sell it again for money and doesn't care about your data, so I wouldn't be too worried about that.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward, now that you can cancel the erase request once you find your device, the best bet seems to be to send a remote lock or remote wipe as you best guess and then monitor.

- [Can I recall (cancel) the erase my iPhone command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415178/can-i-recall-cancel-the-erase-my-iphone-command)